# Issue with Gmail addon needing dynamic auth url

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

We are creating a Gmail add-on that integrates with a CRM product. The product is single-tenant and every client has their own site path under our domain. Each client also has their own path to authorize with, e.g. `https://example.com/siteA/oauth/authorize`.

When setting up the custom auth screens, it looks like we are expected to know the url to assign to a click event on the auth button.

```
authButton2 = CardService.newTextButton().setText('Begin Authorization!')
    .setAuthorizationAction(CardService.newAuthorizationAction()
        .setAuthorizationUrl(authurl));
```

I would like to have some user input before this point. I was playing with an input field where the user could type their site name an then click the authorize button although I was not able to overwrite the original `authurl` supplied to the `setAuthorizationUrl` method.

Ideally it would be nice if the add-ons had a way to store some one-time input (like "site name" in this example) so we would not have to ask again, but I have not found anything like this.

This seems like we need a central auth endpoint but am trying to avoid this.

Anyone have any experience with this or any ideas?

Comment: Why would a client need to have their own oauth path? The auth url typically takes the user to a screen (assuming oauth2) where they authorize your app (by providing their user credentials) to act on their behalf. The oauth url end point is meant to be universal. Can you share any details/documentation about the CRM product?

Comment: Each client has their own site under our domain. ie)https://example.com/sitea / https://example.com/siteb. The architecture lends itself to single tenant sites. Each site has their own auth url under the site ie) https://example.com/sitea/oauth/authorize / https://example.com/siteb/oauth/authorize. The gmail addon really wants to verify if the user currently has access by hitting a test endpoint or something of the sort. At this point we really need to have the site name the user intends to authorize against but I cannot find a way to store this per install of the app or get initial user input

Comment: You might want to rethink your oauth implementation (assuming its possible for you to change it). I don't think this approach complies with how oauth flows are intended to work (oauth endpoints are not meant to be dynamic).

Comment: I am thinking about trying to do this. However lets say that I do set up a universal oauth site that all clients can authenticate against. Another issue I can see is that the api itself is not universal, still under each site root. Since the addin wants to ping a test method or something of the sort initally I can see this still being a problem. Any ideas here?

Comment: Not to sound condescending but I get the feeling that you don't fully grasp how oauth2 flows are meant to work. I'm guessing you've been tasked with implementing an OAuth2 flow for a CRM. So you might want to start with the specs as detailed [here](https://oauth.net/2/). If you need a good high-level overview of an OAuth2 workflow I recommend watching the following video [Workflow of Auth 2.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPbvxxslDTU)

Comment: Lol, more or less. The authorization code flow is the flow I am working and feel like a have a good grasp on the flow and the spec itself albeit this project is defiantly learning on the job. We are trying to use this for multiple integrations via google/zapier etc... I am pretty sure we cannot do what we are trying here but wanted to give it a try. Am able to do this with other integration like apps we are using. But I think you are right about the centralized authentication aspect of this.

Comment: The plan right now is to to keep the single tenatent sites/apis (not able to change this) and setup a centralized authentication site. Here the user can supply their sitename,username/ and pwd. This site will issue a token if suscesful that the integrations can use the make api requests. Granted the machinekey settings are the same on the website farm/auth server I think this should work and probably satify the needs we have here and possibly in the future

Comment: Also FWIW I did stumble upon a "properties" like feature in the Addons, do not think it will help what I was trying to do initially but...

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build the authorization button using the proper url after you get it from the user input.

You can't modify that button once you create it. Rather than modify it, just create the button after you receive the url and reload that card. Or put the authorization button a new card that you push to the top once you receive user input on the auth url.

Comment: Works especially in the scenario where we are not able to have a centralized auth server. In the recommendations they recommend to return 1 card for the auth screen (so the cards don't stack). This card can have actions to the Navigaton control to pop and push a new card to the stack.